# Synapse Pipeline transform XML

Tags: xml, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-pipeline

I have a transformation requirement where source XML document in an ADLS Gen 2 storage container needs to be transformed and stored as a separate XML document in another ADLS Gen 2 storage container. The following link suggests that Synapse Pipeline supports XML as a source but not a sink:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-xml

Just wondering if this is possible or not? Effective want to use Synapse Pipeline to do the equivalent of a XSL-T transformation.

Thanks and regards,
Andrew

Comment: It is not supported.  Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-troubleshoot-xml

Comment: Some database languages support xml.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/query/formats/xml#read-and-write-xml-data

Answer (score 0):

It seems that copying in binary format works fine, but if you are attempting to have Azure Data Factory (ADF) generate XML as Sink, that might not be achievable.

As per the [Troubleshoot the XML format connector in Azure Data Factory and Azure Synapse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-troubleshoot-xml)

[image]

Comment: Thanks - seems like a pretty big limitation. Would be easiser using a Logic App / Function to run an XSL-T